# Excel VBA retrieve "Last Modified By" for a list of filepaths in a spreadsheet (ideally as a function?)

Tags: excel, vba

This is my 2nd attempt at writing this question and hopefully I can make it make more sense this time around!

Basically I have created a macro that scan any given folder (and sub-folders within it) and list filepath/filename of every file (using FSO) and, through a series of Excel formulas, test whether the filenames adhere to a specific naming convention. So far so good.

What I now need is, for filenames that have failed to meet the required convention, to identify the user ID of the person who last saved the file (i.e. last modified BY).

Some of these folders contain hundreds of thousands of documents and therefore rather than building this functionality into the existing macro and potentially significantly slowing performance, I want this to run separately, after I have extracted the fails into another sheet/workbook.

If this can be created as a function this would be awesome but any solution is appreciated.

Hope that makes sense.

Thank you :)

[How the data is structured](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AWqjQ.png)

Comment: What exactly is the question? It sounds like you know how to open a file in a list and get the "Last Author". Is the main issue how to make it efficiently open a list of files, that don't have any logic to where they're stored?  How do you get that list to begin with?

Comment: @BruceWayne Apologies if it is worded badly. The question is, how do I efficiently return the last user for a list of files that already exists.

Answer (score 1):

> so I imagine opening and closing will take forever for the bigger lists!

You can try this without opening the file

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim objFolder As Object
    Dim FileName As Variant, Path As Variant

    FileName = "Sample.xlsx"
    Path = "C:\Users\routs\Desktop\Sid"

    Set objFolder = CreateObject("Shell.Application").Namespace(Path)

    Debug.Print objFolder.GetDetailsOf(objFolder.Items.Item(FileName), 20)
End Sub
```

For me `20` works in Win 10. You may have to use the below code to find the relevant number for `Extended File Properties`. The below code was adapted from the [MS site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/tn-archive/ee176615(v=technet.10))

```
Sub GetProperties()
    Dim objFolder As Object
    Dim i As Long

    Set objFolder = CreateObject("Shell.Application").Namespace("C:\Users\routs\Desktop\Sid")

    For i = 0 To 34
       Debug.Print i & vbTab & objFolder.GetDetailsOf("Sample.xlsx", i)
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Siddarth will check this code as soon as my Excel is freed from a macro that's currently running!

Answer (score 0):

You can get the last modified and last accessed date like this:

```
Sub lastDate()
    Dim objFSO As Object, objFolder As Object, objFile As Object

    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder("pathToFolder")

    For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
        Debug.Print objFile.DateLastAccessed
        Debug.Print objFile.DateLastModified
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you M. Getrost however it's the username of the last person to save the file that I need and as far as I am aware, this is not retrievable from the FSO.